# Approximating an ODE with polynomial interpolation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the scalar ODE:

$$ y'(t) = f(t,y), ~ \\ y(0) = y_0.$$
together with the set of numbers $0 \le c_1 < c_2 < \dots < c_s \le 1.$

Let,
$t_n = n\,\Delta t$ for $n = 0,1,\ldots,$ for some $\Delta t > 0;$ in the interval $[t_{n-1},t_n],$ we consider:
$$\phi(t_{n-1}) = y_{n-1} \\
\phi'(\tau_i) = f(\tau_i,\phi(\tau_i)), ~ ~ i \in \{1, \dots, s\}. $$

where $\tau_i = t_{n-1} + c_i \, \Delta t$ for $i = 1, \dots,s.$ Setting $y_n = \phi(t_n)$. Why does this above process define a piecewise polynomial approximation of $y$? If we consider the successive intervals $[t_{n-1},t_n].$

I thought it looked like hermite interpolation but don't we need $\phi'(t_n) =  f(t_i,\phi(t_i))$ for that? Thanks.

Comment: This is also called a "collocation method", the Euler, implicit trapezoidal and midpoint method being low-order ones. Where does the polynomial character of $\phi$ over the single segments come from, other interpolation methods would give non-polynomial segments.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Would a piecewise polynomial interpolation of $y$ over the interval $[t_{n-1},t_n]$ basically be

$$s_j(x) = y_j - \frac{t_j-x}{t_j - t_{j-1}}(y_j - y_{j-1}),$$

in this case?

Comment: Yes, for the first and second order methods. What makes the method is of course how the slope is determined from the ODE.